# Send-MailMessage Languages

Tags: powershell

I have been able to send massages using the function Send-MailMessage in PS for both gmail and hotmail accounts. However, I have tried to use languages other than english in the subject and budy but it shows up as "????" in the recieved email.

is it possible to use different languages?

FYI: I did get a lot of Japanes characters when I was figuring out the Send-MailMessage function when ever I tried to add attachments or somthing. so I believe characters other than english should be able to be sent.

Comment: Did you set the value for `-Encoding`?
`$ascii = New-Object System.Text.ASCIIEncoding
send-mailmessage -enconding $ascii -to .. -from`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am just learning PS ( Scripting even (: ) I have been tiring to apply this method but no luck yet. I will update you once I get something. Would be nice if you could direct me to where I can learn about -Encoding

Comment: Ask google ;-) . Have a look at the official microsoft docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-6

Comment: Or have a look here: https://powershell.org/forums/topic/send-mailmessage-encoding-issue-in-powershell-4-0/

Comment: it seems to be working when I use below. Now I need to find out how to format and how to make it start from the right :) many thinks for your help

Comment: $msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage 
      $smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer) 
        $smtp.EnableSsl = $true 
        $msg.From = "$From"  
        $msg.To.Add("$To") 
        $msg.Attachments.Add("$Attachments") 
        #$msg.BodyEncoding = [system.Text.Encoding]::Unicode 
        #$msg.SubjectEncoding = [system.Text.Encoding]::Unicode 
        $msg.IsBodyHTML = $true  
        $msg.Subject = "$Job Job Application " 
        $msg.Body= $Body
        $SMTP.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("$From", "$pass"); 
        $smtp.Send($msg)

Comment: You should write this in an answer and mark it as an answer. If somebody else is having the same problem, they can find the solution much easier than reading the comments.. And thanks for reporting back :-)